# Calling a Python function from HTML

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

Im writing a webapplication, where im trying to display the connected USB devices. I found a Python function that does exactly what i want but i cant really figure out how to call the function from my HTML code, preferably on the click of a button.

Comment: You can't do it with only your html code. However, you can still setup a flask server, use the button to communicate with the flask server and get that to run your python code instead.

Comment: just for the record, the above comment would execute the code on your server - e.g. you would detect your server's USB ports rather than the user's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple answer: you can't. the code would have to be run client-side, and no browser would execute potentially malicious code automatically (and not every system has a python interpreter installed).

the only thing you can execute client-side (without the user taking action, e.g. downloading a program or browser add-on) is javascript.